# Make left quote printed out as it is typed

Tags: pdftex

I want to make the left quote,

> `

printed out with pdflatex exactly like the one above (it is also displayed like that when I typed on my Mac).

I tried with following ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
not this one `

verbatim also does not work: \verb|`|, \verb|\`|

\texttt{`} is texttt, but also not correct

this one \`~is correct displayed

this one \`is not correct displayed again
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The fourth line was printed out correctly. However, I cannot make the left quote close to the text after it. It will become the small quote above the character like the next line (`ì`). How do I remove the space?

Comment: ``\def\leftquote{\`{}}``? I mean you already found out which one worked...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your objective correctly, you're looking to typeset the left-hand apostrophe as a standalone "grave" accent. As you've discovered,

```
\`{}
```

gets the job done. Alternatively, you could type `\char18`.

*Additional Remarks*:

- If the `T1` font encoding scheme is in use, one must type `\char0` instead of `\char18` in order to generate a standalone grave symbol.
- If the `upquote` package is loaded,

  ```
  \verb+`+
  ```

  also generates a straight rather than curly left quote -- in *verbatim* mode.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
standalone grave accent: \`{}
\verb|\char18| in various font shapes
\qquad upright Roman: \char18
\qquad monospaced: \texttt{\char18}
\qquad italic: \textit{\char18}
\qquad sans-serif: \textsf{\char18}
\end{document}
```